# Are api_id and api_hash secrets?

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

I am very confused about this topic, I am creating a program and to extract media from a telegram channel I wanted to use
the Telethon api, are therefore necessary api_id and api_hash, if then I wanted to distribute this software is safe to do this considering that there are these two data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are personal and secret, you should distribute the software without your API ID or hash. Every user can get its own values from https://my.telegram.org and set it in a config file or similar. Then you can load it from it.

Comment: Not entirely correct. API ID and hash should be embedded in the application distributed to end users (end users should *not* be providing their own API ID and hash when running the application; official clients have their own values embedded and don't ask the user to enter theirs!). Unfortunately in Python the application is plain source code unless obfuscated so it would be visible. So while it shouldn't be public, it still should be distributed to end-users.